# Full page background for Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is it possible to set a background image in Excel that extends to the whole page and not only the region with cells?

In principle I would like to cover the maximum possible printable area.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. In the page setup screen, set the margins to 0, which will remove any spaces between the printable border and the cells. Then add a column and row as spacer if you don't want to print the cells as close to the border as possible.

Do note, that if your printer is able to do borderless printer, and it is a laser printer, that you are not printing outside of the paper. If you do this, you'll print on your fuser and that means ink will be left on the next hundreds of prints.

Comment: Seems to work but when I print it, there is no background at all

Comment: Given your question, I assumed you already figured that out. But this is a different question, and you should start a new question for that part.

Comment: Not really sure: as far as I have see Background images are never printed. So yes the question should be "how to print a background" but then also your answer does not make sense: I can reduce the margins but this has nothing to do with printing as the background is ignored.